# JBoss 7 JMX Documentation

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jmx

We have a generic system that uses JMX to monitor various application servers, and I am now required to configure monitoring for JBoss 7.

we used to rely on the fact that previous versions of JBoss implemented JSR-77 to identify "interesting" MBeans and give the users the option to choose what kind of data they want to see. According to [this document](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide) and what I saw with JConsole, JSR-77 is no longer supported in JBoss 7, and I've read that the entire JMX subsystem was redesigned.

Is there an API documentation somewhere that describes the new design?

I want to know if the MBeans are organized in some systematic way that would make it easier for me to scan and configure them programmatically. For example, with JSR-77 I could use the j2eeType and name key properties to allow my users to collect a certain stat for a certain type of J2EE object (say service time for all servlets), without having to write code that is aware of each and every J2EE type.

How can I do something like that with JBoss 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know any documentation about this. With JBoss 7 Red Hat wanted to reduce the MBeans dramatically (the user should prefer the CLI). But after some user protest, they extended the MBeans in version 7.2 again.